# Using Em Dashes in Contact Form Arrays

Tags: html, html-encode

novice web developer here. I'm building a contact order form for my website, and the field in question I'm using uses radio buttons to offer the user an option between X and Y. If I'm using em dashes, it will show up just fine on the visual side of things, but regardless of whether or not I'm using the dash characater for the value of the option, it won't retain the value if there are any errors. Allow me to explain.

```
<div class="fieldwrap">
  <div class="formlabel">
    <p>Color Options<span style="color:red">*</span></p>
  </div>
  <label>
   <input type="radio" value="As shown—without logo" name="color"
   <?php  if ($fields['Color']=='As shown—without logo') echo 'checked="checked"' ; ?>>
   As shown&#8212;without logo
  </label><br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="As shown—with logo" name="color" 
    <?php if ($fields['Color']=='As shown—with logo') echo 'checked ="checked"' ; ?>>
    As shown&#8212;with logo</label>
</div>
```

So I'm trying to make sure it will keep the option checked in the case the form returns an error, usually due to form validation or incorrect user inputs.

Now, this works okay in Chrome and Internet Explorer, but Firefox won't keep these values checked. I'm 99% sure this has to do with my charset property, which mine is set to:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Any ideas for what I need to do to make it play nicely across all browsers?

Comment: Note: the [tag:dash] tag refers to the `dash` shell, not to the punctuation mark of the same name.

Comment: You should use simpler values like `with_logo`, `without_logo`. Em Dashes etc. just need to be there in the UI, you don't need them as data in your backend.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using "user-friendly" values. Instead, it should be something like...

```
<input type="radio" value="nologo" name="color" /> As shown&mdash;without logo
```

Your server will then handle this "nologo" value, and when presenting it to the user, will give back a more readable thing.

Obviously how you do this is up to you, but the general idea of "human data" vs. "computer data" is what I'm getting at here. The server doesn't need to deal with the text the user sees. Also, this allows you to change the exact wording of what "nologo" means without having to change your entire data structure.

Comment: The problem is, the values will be printed in the email when the form is submitted. I can figure out a workaround, but I was really hoping to learn how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Don't print the raw values. Define what these values mean and then send the meaningful result in the email.

Answer (score 0):

The `value=".."` supplied in your radio inputs (that the PHP script checks for) is not displayed to the end user, so it doesn't really matter what you set these values to as long as they are unique. The easiest solution would be to just avoid using the em dash in the value attribute.

Try this:

```
<div class="fieldwrap">
  <div class="formlabel">
    <p>Color Options<span style="color:red">*</span></p>
  </div>
  <label>
   <input type="radio" value="without" name="color"
   <?php  if ($fields['Color']=='without') echo 'checked="checked"' ; ?>>
   As shown&#8212;without logo
  </label><br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="with" name="color" 
    <?php if ($fields['Color']=='with') echo 'checked ="checked"' ; ?>>
    As shown&#8212;with logo</label>
</div>
```

The user will still see the em dash since you included that as text after the radio button input.

Comment: The values are printed in an email when the form is submitted.

Comment: Can you dump the $_REQUEST field (do var_dump($_REQUEST)) and tell me what the output is on Firefox after doing a submission?

Comment: Can you write var_dump($_REQUEST); in your php code and then tell me what the result of this variable dump is when you submit the form?  $_REQUEST is the PHP variable that holds GET and POST data (that is data passed via a URL parameter or via a POST request)

Comment: Could you show the var_dump for the original code that you wrote with the em dash in the value attribute? It looks like you showed the dump using the code I suggested. It seems like you want to keep the em dash in the value field, so I'm trying to see how Firefox sends that data.

Comment: It seems my issues run a bit deeper. Firefox sends the form just fine, but in general it isn't returning any values at all. I'll have to investigate, or maybe start a new post.

Comment: I think I found my problem. I found my <charset="UTF-8"> tag outside of the head. I do the majority of my work on Chrome, and apparently it can work just fine with this mistake. Firefox seems to be less lenient :)